# SQL get all values within a time range - AND the one before that

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where every `ActorId` has a `Value`, but the `Value` will change over time and we keep track of all changes to these values.

Example:

```
Id  ActorId     Value   Timestamp
--------------------------------
1   5           10      2019-01-05
2   8           8       2019-01-07
3   8           5       2019-01-08
4   5           15      2019-01-11
5   3           12      2019-01-11
6   3           7       2019-01-12
7   3           14      2019-01-14
[...]
```

If we load everything into memory it's quite easy to check for every `Actor` what the value will be at any moment in time (or it will be *null / undefined* if it has never been set before the query date). Matter of fact is that I actually need to send all this data to the browser and do this within JavaScript.

The problem is that the full table will become really, really large. Both in **unique ActorIds** and in **value changes** per ActorId.

Usually I just need a relative small selection of `ActorId`s and a short period of time - say two months.

I could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ActorValue]
WHERE 
    ActorId IN (5, 8, 12, [...])
    AND Timestamp >= '2019-02-01' 
    AND Timestamp <= '2019-04-01'
```

And send these results to JavaScript for further processing.

The problem is that I also need the value *at the start* of the period. So for every ActorId I need the values within the date range and **one value-change before that**.

What is the best way to solve this problem without loading all value changes into memory.

So what I'm in theory looking for is something like:

```
 AND Timestamp >= '2019-02-01' -- plus the entry before this date, grouped by ActorId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `lead()`:

```
SELECT av.*
FROM (SELECT av.*, 
             LEAD(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY ActorId ORDER BY Timestamp) as next_timestamp
      FROM ActorValue av
      WHERE ActorId IN (5, 8, 12, [...])
     ) av
WHERE next_Timestamp >= '2019-02-01' 
      Timestamp <= '2019-04-01';
```

Comment: Ok, you guys are way faster then I expected. I am actually still implementing this, but I expected to add a bounty so I placed my question early. There's a lot of new knowledge for me in this answer and it seems to make sense. I'll assume it works and accept this one for now! Thanks a lot, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what this can be solved by adding more conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Either the record belongs to the analysis interval, or it is the most recent record for before the start of the analysis period for the concerned actor. The latter condition can be expressed using a `NOT EXISTS` condition and a correlated subquery.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ActorValue] a
WHERE 
    ActorId IN (5, 8, 12, [...])
    AND 
    (
        (
            Timestamp >= '2019-02-01' 
            AND Timestamp <= '2019-04-01'
        )
        OR (
            Timestamp < '2019-02-01' 
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM [ActorValue] a1 
                WHERE 
                    a1.ActorId = a.ActorId 
                    AND a1.Timestamp < '2019-02-01' 
                    AND a1.Timestamp > a.Timestamp
            )
        )
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, thanks for your answer. Your answer seems to make sense too, but the other one seems a bit more elegant and I had to pick one :) thanks for the time you put in helping other people.